# jQuery draggable hanging object

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

How to recreate a very nice effect form this website: http://bigdropinc.com? If you look at the top right corner, they have a ribbon saying "Drag down" and when your cursor hover the ribbon, it starts following the cursor, bouncing a little. If you click and drag it down, a box from the top appears. Basically I am just really curious about the technology, and would like to learn how to recreate something similar. I would prefer if this could be done without any plugins. Either pure JS or in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could find is the forkit library.

https://github.com/hakimel/forkit.js

You can see a demo here.

http://lab.hakim.se/forkit-js/

This would probably be the same script they are using..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You are probably right.. seems like it is the same.. I will try to look it through..